# WSO2AM - How to get API Version inside a property?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Good afternoon everyone.

I am working on inflow sequence, and i need to get my API Version.
I can use a substring function but i would like to create a generic sequence.

I tried with 
`<property name="myVersion" expression="get-property('Version')"/>`
and with "version","VERSION" ...

How can i get my API Version with a  mediator, or an other mediator ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

`SYNAPSE_REST_API_VERSION`

More: http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html

Comment: That's exactly what i am looking for. Thank you Bee, you helped me again !